# Table header is not aligned and this.setState is not working within private method in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap-table

[image][image]

The Bootstrap Table header is not aligned with the data, am I missing any style? I'm using

```
import { BootstrapTable, TableHeaderColumn } from 'react-bootstrap-table';
```

I have marked in the attached picture where this.setState is not working in a function within  private method.

Comment: `this` has different behavior when referenced from within a standard function as compared to from within an arrow function. Have you tried defining `deleteRecord` as an arrow function? (i.e., instead of `function deleteRecord(row: { id: string; }) {` , use `deleteRecord = (row: { id: string; }) => {` )

Comment: `this.setState` is not accessible because you enclose it with a `function(){}` inside another function. Try saving `const self = this` in the parent function and then inside the child function `self.setState()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've fixed the header alignment issue by

```
import 'react-bootstrap-table/dist/react-bootstrap-table-all.min.css';
```

Answer (score 0):

exists possibility and using default Bootstrap code in need component, but in this case  you must use CDN links who is need  for normal work of Bootstrap from index.html file in your app